# Draw graph of limit definition

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I need to draw a graph definition of limit. I need a Tikz picture like this

[image: Limit]

I don't know how draw the red lines. Can someone help me?

Comment: Consider [pgfplots](https://ctan.org/pkg/pgfplots).

Comment: How did you draw the rest? TikZ has the path operations `-|` and `|-` which can be used here.

Comment: If you only need the red lines, then add a minimal working example of what you already did, and you would definitely have answers. In particular, using the `-|` option for a path would be very easy to do.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[thin,-latex] (-.1,0)--(6.6,0) node[right] () {$x$};
        \draw[thin,-latex] (0,-1)--(0,3) node[above] () {$y$};
        \draw[blue,line width=2pt] plot [domain=0.5:4.5,smooth] (\x,{.02*exp(\x)+.3});
        \node[blue] at (5.5,2) () {\large $y=f(x)$};
        \draw[red,dashed] (3,0) node[below] {$a-\delta$}--(3,{.02*exp(3)+.3})--(0,{.02*exp(3)+.3}) node[left] {$ l-\epsilon $};
        \draw[red,dotted] (3.5,0) node[above, fill=white] {$ a $}--(3.5,{.02*exp(3.5)+.3})--(0,{.02*exp(3.5)+.3}) node[left] {$l$};
        \draw[red,dashed] (4,0) node[below] {$ a+\delta $}--(4,{.02*exp(4)+.3})--(0,{.02*exp(4)+.3}) node[left] {$ l+\epsilon  $};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Note: I don't like double arrowed axes. If You want replace `-latex` with `latex-latex`.

**EDIT**:
If you like better this graph

[image]

You have to change tree lines of code this way:

```
\draw[red,dashed] (3,-.5) node[below] {\small $a-\delta$}--(3,{.02*exp(3)+.3})--(0,{.02*exp(3)+.3}) node[left] {\small$ l-\epsilon $};
\draw[red,dotted] (3.5,0) node[below] {\small $ a $}--(3.5,{.02*exp(3.5)+.3})--(0,{.02*exp(3.5)+.3}) node[left] {\small $l$};
\draw[red,dashed] (4,-.5) node[below] {\small $a+\delta $}--(4,{.02*exp(4)+.3})--(0,{.02*exp(4)+.3}) node[left] {\small$l+\epsilon  $};
```